# Action on subscribe() and unsubscribe()

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, subject

in RxJS I'd like to take some special action once an Observer subscribes to an Observable and when he unsubscribes. I can of course overwrite the `subscribe()` and `unsubscribe()` methods, but that seems crud.
Isn't there a way during creation of the observable to supply callbacks that get called whenever someone subscribes/unsubscribes?
BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [`Observable.create`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/observable.md#disposing-observable-executions) is for. You can create your own observable with specified attach/detach handlers, and can even wrap existing observables with just 2 additional lines of code.

```js
const obs = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  console.log('attach');
  // If you want to wrap another observable, call this:
  // const subs = other.subscribe(observer);
  return () => {
    // subs.unsubscribe();
    console.log('detach');
  };
});

console.log('subscribe subscription1');
const subscribtion1 = obs.subscribe(() => {});
console.log('subscribe subscription2');
const subscribtion2 = obs.subscribe(() => {});
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('subscribtion1.dispose()');
  subscribtion1.unsubscribe();
}, 500);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('subscribtion2.dispose()');
  subscribtion2.unsubscribe();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.0-rc.4/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm definitely not yet into reactive programming. Thanks a lot for the explanation.